# gerrit suppress draft email but allow drafts to be visible

Tags: configuration, gerrit

I have recently set View Drafts to "Allow" for a group.

However, it now sends an email to that group anytime someone creates or edits a draft. Is there any way to either:

1. (Ideal) Disable all emails for draft commits
2. Also send a mail when someone publishes a draft so that everyone knows it's OK to view it.
3. Inject some headers or something in the body of the email indicating that it is in 'Draft' so that people can filter it out/in as needed.

Solution 3 will require a solution to 2 also I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like if each user sets the watched project and in the only if: section to -is:draft I get exactly what I want. I think the question now is 'how to make this universal or the default?'